# Collectstatic deleting wagtail blog images

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, wagtail

I have a wagtail site that I deploy using elasticbeanstalk. When I deploy collectstatic is ran:

```
.platform/hooks/postdeploy
#!/bin/sh

source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate
python /var/app/current/manage.py migrate
python /var/app/current/manage.py createsu
python /var/app/current/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

I have found that this has the effect of deleting any images that are in my blog posts. I assume this is because the blog posts have been made using the page editor (of the deployed site) and are not on my local machine like the rest of the static files

How should I be setting things so that I do not delete the images everytime collectstatic is ran?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL settings in your project (which define where uploaded files will be placed) are set to something different to STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL (which define the location of static files that are deployed as part of the app).

Comment: Thanks, however these were set differently yet the problem was still occuring ```STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'psymatik/media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: I think I need to se up amazon s3 to hold the media files I followed advice atL https://blog.theodo.com/2019/07/aws-s3-upload-django/
and also added "storages" to installed_apps and the below to settings:

AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

(this is from https://wagtail.org/blog/amazon-s3-for-media-files/) But I can't upload images through the admin ( after pressing upload the wheel spins for a bit but then nothing happens.